# Is there a minimum possible size change in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I wrote some `JavaScript` code to animate `CSS` properties of elements. I pass the following arguments to the function: **amount**, **interval**, and **duration**; amount being the change in the property (for example 200 could mean add 200 pixels to the element's width), interval being the time between two consecutive changes, and duration being the total duration of the animation.

The code works fine unless I pass the arguments in a way that the change in each interval becomes very small (like a tiny fraction of a pixel).

I know the code is working fine theoretically, as I get the change in console.

Any ideas about the problem?

Cheers.

UPDATE: the code:

```
function handleTimer (amount, interval, duration, execute, element) {
    let i = 0;
    let current = 0;
    let stepsCount = countSteps(interval, duration);
    let stepLength = calcStepLength(stepsCount, amount);
    let count = setTimeout(function addOneMore () {
        if ( i < stepsCount -1 ){
            i++;
            current += stepLength;

            execute(stepLength, element);
            if (current < amount) {
                count = setTimeout(addOneMore, interval)
            }
        } else {
            current = amount;
            execute(amount - (stepsCount -1) * stepLength, element);
        }
    }, interval)
}

function countSteps (interval, duration) {
    let remainder = duration % interval;
    let stepsCount;
    if (remainder) {
        stepsCount = Math.floor(duration / interval) + 1;
    } else {
        stepsCount = duration / interval;
    }
    return stepsCount;
}
function calcStepLength(stepsCount, amount) {
    return amount / stepsCount;
}


function resizeWidth (amount, element) {
    let widthSTR = $(element).css('width');
    let width = parseInt( widthSTR.substr( 0 , widthSTR.length - 2 ) );

    $(element).css('width', `${width + amount}px`);

}
```

So this:

```
handleTimer(218, 5, 200, resizeWidth, '.box');
```

works fine, but this:

```
handleTimer(218, 5, 2000, resizeWidth, '.box');
```

doesn't.

UPDATE 2:
I know browsers are super accurate with pixels, like when you use percentages. Of course the value will be rounded before rendering since displays cant display half pixels, but the value is still calculated accurately.
I don't know at what decimal the rounding occurs.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: It's better if you share the code through plunkr.

Comment: I would suggest 1px would be the minimum as some monitors can't render less than a pixel and it would be hard to see any changes less than a px with the naked eye

Comment: Remove `parseInt` and it should work

Comment: Didn't help, also tried with +(I have to convert string to number at some point).
@CristianTraìna

Comment: I meant that `parseInt` will round your number, so in this context `parseFloat` would be preferred. Browsers won't complain if you set `0.333333333px` width somewhere

Comment: It solved the problem man, thanks a lot. @CristianTraìna

Comment: Would you mind if I answer the question too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `parseInt` is rounding your number up.

Pay attention to this line:

```
let width = parseInt( widthSTR.substr( 0 , widthSTR.length - 2 ) );
```

if width is a decimal number, like `22.5px`, it will be rounded up to `22`.

If `amount` is less than 1, it won't reach `23` and when you round up the number again, you'll get `22` again and it becomes a loop.

You have two solutions:

- Use another variable to save the width value, avoiding to writing and reading it from CSS:

  ```
  let initialWidth = $(element).css('width');
  let savedWidth = widthSTR.substr(0, initialWidth, initialWidth.length - 2 ) );
  function resizeWidth (amount, element) {
    savedWidth += amount;
    $(element).css('width', `${savedWidth}px`);
  }
  ```
- Just use `parseFloat` in place of `parseInt` to don't round your number up:

  ```
  let width = parseFloat( widthSTR.substr( 0 , widthSTR.length - 2 ) );
  ```